# Move documents folder in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have one doubt how can I move my documents folder and others to my other partition, I red that if I restart my computer I will lost the symbolic link.

So how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just so long as a symbolic link isn't created in a location like `/tmp` it should be persistent.

Give it a try.  Create the symbolic link and reboot your computer.

<sup>Side note: Always ensure you have a good backup of your data</sup>